# Prove that the given linear map is injective

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a fixed positive integers and $B \in \mathbb{R}_+$ also be fixed. For a fixed $M>0$, let $f:[-B,B]^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i M^i$. My aim is to prove the following:

Prove that one can always find a fixed positive real number $M$ (dependent only on $B$ and $n$) such that $f$ is an injective map.

If such an $M$ does not exist in the above question, one can assume that each $x_i$ can take only  a fixed set of countable values in $[-B,B]$. In other words, the map $f$ is defined only for a countable subset of $[-B,B]^n$. In this reduced case, can $f$ be injective?

My attempt: Let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=f(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ for some $(x_1,\ldots,x_n),(y_1,\ldots,y_n) \in [-B,B]^n$. Thus, $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)M^i=0$. After this step, I am stuck and unable to procced further about how to choose such an $M$ such that the above equation does't have any solution.

Comment: Is it given that $a_i \neq b_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$?

Comment: Yeah.Or atleast one $a_i \neq b_i$.

Comment: Are all the $a's$ and $b's$ specified in advance?  Then you just have a polynomial with some non-zero coefficients.

Comment: @lulu: I edited the question a bit. Please check.

Comment: This doesn't work.  If $M>1$ then take any $b_1\neq 0$ in the range and define $a_n=\frac {b_1}{M^{n-1}}$, all others $0$.  If $M≤1$ then take $b_2\neq 0$ in the range and let $a_1=b_2\,M$, all others $0$.

Comment: This question is a lot more clear. Thanks for the edit. However, I do not understand how you deduce $f$ is only defined on a countable subset of $[-B, B]^n$. Also, if $f$ is only defined on a countable subset, it can still be injective as long as it is not surjective, so I do not think your first argument is going to work.

Comment: @NobleMushtak: If it's not able to prove it for the general case, then I meant that assume $f$ is defined only on a fixed set of countable values in $[-B,B]^n$. Is that clear now?

Comment: @pikachuchameleon Oh, so it is a reduced version of the problem. That makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

The general statement is definitely false for $n > 1$. $f(0, 0)=0$, but we can also choose some $0 < \epsilon < \min(B, BM)$ so that $\left(-\epsilon, \frac \epsilon M\right) \in [-B, B]^2$ and thus in the domain of $f$. Thus, we have the following:
$$f\left(-\epsilon, \frac \epsilon M\right)=-\epsilon M+\frac \epsilon M M^2=-\epsilon M+\epsilon M=0$$
Therefore, $f(0, 0)=f\left(-\epsilon, \frac \epsilon M\right)$ and $f$ is not injective.

However, I think the reduced statement is actually true. Let $D$ be the domain of $f$. For any two unequal ${\bf x}, {\bf y} \in D$, $f({\bf x})=f({\bf y})$ means that $\sum_{i=1}^n ({\bf x}_i-{\bf y}_i)M^i=0$. Since the left side of this equation is a non-zero polynomial of degree at most $n$ in terms of $M$, there are at most $n$ values of $M$ which satisfies this equality.

We have the following:

- Since $D$ is countable, there are a countable number of pairs of unequal ${\bf x}, {\bf y} \in D$.
- Given a specific pair of ${\bf x}, {\bf y} \in D$, there are a finite number of $M$ where $f({\bf x})=f({\bf y})$.

Therefore, overall, there are a countable set of $M$ where $f({\bf x})=f({\bf y})$ is true for any ${\bf x}, {\bf y} \in D$. On the other hand, there are an uncountable number of positive real numbers, so choose a positive number that is not in the described countable set. For this $M$, $f({\bf x}) \neq f({\bf y})$ for all ${\bf x}, {\bf y} \in D$, which means $f$ is injective.

Comment: I modified the question a bit. Please verify.

Comment: @pikachuchameleon I have revised my answer. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, more or less that resolves the question. But, how do you make sure that $\frac{\epsilon}{M} \leq B$ in the counter-example?

Comment: $\epsilon$ can be any positive number, so we simply pick a $0 < \epsilon < BM$. If you want a specific example, $\epsilon=\frac{BM} 2$ works.

Comment: Okay. Then how do you ensure that $BM/2 < B$. Remember that I want injectivity on the domain $[-B,B]$. Also, in the second part of the above solution regarding the reduced case, it doesn't matter if they are bounded right? I think your solution doesn't use that.

Comment: Sorry, I should've written that we pick a $0 < \epsilon < \min(B, BM)$. This way, $\epsilon < B$ and $\epsilon < BM$, so $\frac \epsilon M < B$. Also, you are right, the boundedness does not matter in the reduced case.